# Connecting AWS EC2 instance using Python Socket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, sockets, amazon-ec2, tcp

Server.py (Running on my aws ec2 instance)

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()
host = socket.gethostbyaddr('aws.ec2.public.ip')[0]
port = 12345
s.bind((host, port))

s.listen(5)
while True:
   c, addr = s.accept()
   print('Got connection from', addr)
   c.send('Thank you for connecting'.encode())
   c.close()
```

Client.py (Running on my local pc)

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()
host = socket.gethostbyaddr('aws.ec2.public.ip')[0]
port = 12345

s.connect((host, port))
print(s.recv(1024).decode())
s.close()
```

> All inbound & outbound TCP traffic granted

The Server code shows no error.
But the Client code says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sohamjain/Desktop/client.py", line 7, in <module>
    s.connect((host, port))
TimeoutError: [Errno 60] Operation timed out
>>>
```

> Connecting to the EC2 instance via rdp client works perfectly

When I run both these scripts on local host they seem to work fine.
But in case of AWS EC2 Instance, it does not.
Where did I go wrong?

Comment: What type of error are you seeing? Can you for example connect from client server to "server" server using SSH for example (you said you have all ports open).

Comment: Also to confirm the instance for `server.py` won't be aware it has that public address. It will only ever understand it has the private IP address as the internet gateway performs NAT translation inbound to map the public IP to the private IP when it receives traffic. This can be confirmed by running `ifconfig`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have just encountered your situation:

As Chris Williams mentioned in a reply to your question, you cannot use the public IP address when binding the listening socket on the EC2 instance. Change that to use the private IP and it should work.

Also make sure you enable traffic for the port you are binding from AWS security groups.

Comment: But if you change it to the private IP, you can't really reach it from outside.. so what's the point? It needs to be listening on the actual external IP